# Modelling Bridgnorth Castle, England

Tags: castles

I am building a 1:60 model of the English [Bridgnorth Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridgnorth_Castle). The [tower ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridgnorth_Castle#/media/File:Bridgnorth_castle_DSC00377.JPG) (which leans 15 degrees) clearly shows what had been an inverted, lead covered 'vee' roof (to presumably catch rainwater for drinking.

I am missing any detail as to the bottom gutter and gully, and have a further detailed question: how would the smoke from the fire in the building's hearth escape?

Comment: I would put this question on the history of science site, because there are more scientists there that could give you a better answer.